# how to detect an event "on click" from submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

hello everyone i cant make a "Hello world" i dont know why.with submit_tag i cant set a "hello world".

my haml code:

```
=form_tag products_path, method: :get, remote: true, id: "products_search" do
  =text_field_tag :search,nil, class:"form-control floating-label", placeholder: "Buscar producto..."
  =submit_tag "Buscar", name: nil, class: "btn btn-success bold",id: "button_search"
```

my coffee code

```
$('#button_search').closest('products_search').on "submit", ()->
  alert("hello world")
```

### with "links" works fine for example:

```
$("#products").on "click", ".pagination a", ()->
  alert("hello world")
  return false
```

> but with submit_tag doesn't work fine

someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

> Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or
>   submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit

```
$('#button_search').on "submit", ()->
  alert("hello world")
  return false
```

> with your code doesn't happen anything. is very strange i can make
>   "hello world" with the link's works fine but with submitag i cant do
>   it.

You most likely have other unrelated errors in the page that are breaking it. Below is reproducible example that proves it works:

```js
$("#button_search").on('click', function(){
  alert("Hello world");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="#button_search">
   <input type="submit" id="button_search" />
</form>
```

Comment: with your code doesn't happen anything. is very strange i can make "hello world" with the link's works fine but with submitag i cant do it. im going to update the question for you see that

Comment: No - thats just not how it works. The submit event is fired on the form on all almost every browser ever. Your code is most likely broken in some other way that so that the handler is not working.

Comment: I would suggest that you learn javascript and how to use the browser console before learning coffeescript.

Comment: but my form is remote: true, dont you believe that is different way with remote brother?

Comment: If you are using `remote: true` you should listen for the [Rails UJS events](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) not for the submit event. But that still does not effect the fact that your original code will not work since you are listening for the submit event on the button and not the form.